# CSS: overriding specific selectors with a more general one

Tags: css

I have a CSS stylesheet that specifies the font for each paragraph class:

```
p.body {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    /* (more properties omitted for brevity) */
}
p.bodytextcenter {
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
p.bodytextright {
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

(etc. for dozens of styles).

Now I have to use a different font for some languages. I can do this by making a new selector `p.body[lang="de"]` etc, but I'd have to do that for every style in my list.

Is there a way to specify `p[lang="de"]` and have it apply to all paragraphs with that language attribute? Or would this require me to remove the `font-family` attribute from every paragraph class?

Comment: I'm guessing these rules appear after the p[lang="de"] rule? Otherwise, if the language rule always appears last, it should override all of these (as should p:lang(de) - these are all equally specific).

Comment: but p[lang='de'] is less specific than p.body. AIU, the order only matters when two selectors have the same specificity?

Comment: I just said that they are equally specific. Attribute selectors and class selectors are equally specific.

Comment: @Hobbes, take a look at how CSS selector specificity is calculated: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#specificity

Comment: that explains it, I was going by an incomplete explanation of how to calculate specificity.

Comment: It seems odd that you’re applying a “body” class to each paragraph in the first place. Why are you doing this? What the heck is your page structure?  You should have the main body of the page inside a “main” tag, which gives you `main p` — much simpler to work with!

Comment: The application is CSS paged media. Every paragraph must have a style assigned to it, this is dictated by the application that generates the HTML, 'body' is the default paragraph style.

Comment: I think @StephenR refers to the fact that using class "body" for paragraph elements is at least confusing, regardless of what kind of media your CSS applies to. It's confusing because "body" usually refers to the body of a HTML document and/or the `body` HTML element. Are you the author of the application that generates the HTML along with adding the class `body` to every paragraph? Maybe you're having a case of [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: In HTML5 it would be a great use case for the “section” tag

Comment: I'm not the author of the application. I have been building CSS templates for this application for a while now, and using a classname of 'Body' has not been a problem so far. I'll keep it in mind though.

Comment: @amn I'd accept an answer along those lines.

Comment: Sorry, @Hobbes, I am not following -- along which lines? Without knowing more about your system, the comments pretty much answer your question: yes there is a way -- arrange your CSS rules in such order that rules that apply for the `p[lang="de"]` selector appear _after_ rules for the `p.body`, `p.bodytextcenter` and `p.bodytextright` selectors, because with CSS when specificity is the same it is the order of appearance of rules that decides which properties apply and how their values are computed.

Comment: your comment on how CSS selector specificity is calculated was the key for me. I was under the impression that attribute selectors were less specific than class selectors.

Answer (score 0):

p[lang="de"] this may work but if not you can add !important  on the font family style

Comment: `!important` is generally a hack rather than a solid recommendation; but in order to make a good recommendation we would have to see @hobbes actual HTML

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

`html body p[lang=de]`

...or similar, depending on your actual HTML. You just need to add more levels of specificity.

This can't properly be answered without seeing your HTML; but I'm going to guess that the CSS is poorly structured, and that's what's making this hard for you.  Doing the above is slightly hackish, but syntactically legit.

The rest of this might not help so much now, but good to keep in mind for the next project....

It's best to design your page structure based on the semantic meaning rather than the specific effect. Navigation, article, aside, sidebar; not left, right, bold, etc.  Imagine you have a sidebar on the right.  You could name it "sidebar" or "textright".  But down the road you decide to put it on the left.... or do something completely different on mobile. Now "textright" is just mislabelled.

Even keeping with your current way of doing it, you should note that an element can have multiple classes.  So rather than having:

```
<p class="body">...</p>

<p class="bodytextcenter">...</p>

<p class="bodytextright">...</p>
```

you could have something like:

```
<p class="body">...</p>

<p class="body textcenter">...</p>

<p class="body textright">...</p>
```

With that you can set fonts on `p.body`, and layout on `p.textcenter` and `p.textright`

That's an imperfect answer for the current project, as it would require changing a lot of existing text, but that goes back to the initial issue -- poorly structured CSS.  (And again, without seeing HTML I'm mostly guessing here....)